# Ubuntu for someone who doesn't know code?

Tags: software-installation

I'm considering downloading Ubuntu for a number of reasons, but I don't have any experience with coding... Do you need a lot of coding experience to use ubuntu?

Comment: I am aquainted with an 80-year-old grandmother who uses Ubuntu for all her computer needs and knows precisely *zero* about coding. She isn't complaining!

Comment: Not at all. I've taught about 200 folks at my local community computer reuse center, and about two of them had coding experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any programming experience to use Ubuntu. Ubuntu aims to be similar to Windows in user requirements. The Ubuntu motto is "Linux for human beings".

Comment: ooh that's good! Thank you. Which version is more user friendly? base ubuntu or ubuntu mint?

Comment: @Dopamine Mint isn't Ubuntu (and is anathema to the people here), it's based on Ubuntu but isn't the same thing. Anyway, Mint is probably a good place to start because they will install some extra stuff for you (like video and music codecs) that you probably want. But both Ubuntu and Mint are trying to be very user friendly.

Comment: It more depends on which you like more, can try both and see.  I am also a long time Ubuntu user who couldn't code out of a wet paper bag.  If you have any problems, you will find other people had similar problems and solved it, if you do a google search.  If that doesn't help, we will.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours has a list of downloadable 'flavours' of Ubuntu; nearly everything's the same under the hood, but some are more streamlined (Lubuntu) than others, and some look more Windows-y (MATE) or Mac-ish (Budgie). https://www.fossmint.com/which-ubuntu-flavor-should-you-choose/ Try a few, see which you like.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I'm contacting you now through my new Ubuntu OS!